# SQL Server Database Mail Error/Missing

Tags: sql-server, email, sql-server-2016-express

Current SQL Server:

```
SQL Server 2016 Express SP1
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU7-GDR) (KB4057119) - 13.0.4466.4 (X64)   
Dec 22 2017 11:25:00   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 15063: )
```

- Downloaded Cumulative Update 1 and went through the installation steps
- Downloaded Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5

Database Mail still does not show. **Suggestions?**

Of note, when I click on the download file for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5, it doesn't do anything even when trying to run as an Administrator.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/02/sending-mail-using-sql-server-express-edition/

In SQL server standard and enterprise edition,A DataBase mail functionality in built to sent mail.But in SQL Server express edition,You need either use CLR integration or configure SQL Mail using MSDB system database.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cd59b9cc-21ea-4130-afd1-791124031ada/can-sql-server-express-send-emails?forum=sqlexpress
You can make use of CLR Integration for sending email from SQL Server Express.
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+Express/71341/ 
http://www.vnypatel.com/sending-emails-with-clr-sql-server-express-editions

SQL Server Express does not support database mail.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx